# if then Ternary Operator in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to confirm this but is it possible to have a Ternary Operator in an if-then statement in C++ without the else?

For example:

```
if (ShowDebug) 
{
   DebugRender(); 
}
```

... would be:

```
ShowDebug ? DebugRender();
```

... but I get a:

```
error C2059: syntax error: ';'
```

... then I thought maybe I could avoid a compiler error with having the right syntax but nothing in the else part:

```
ShowDebug ? DebugRender():;
```

... and I still get a:

```
error C2059: syntax error: ';'
```

Any suggestions?  Or is it simply not supported?

Comment: You can add dummy value. If the return type of `DebugRender()` is `void`, `ShowDebug ? DebugRender(): (void)0;`

Comment: Hint: The name of the operator tells you the amount of operands it has to have.

Comment: No; if you only need 'if then', don't use `? :`.  Or use `ShowDebug ? DebugRender() : (void)0;` — but it is better to be clear.

Comment: You could use a dummy value but just because it's in one line it doesn't make your code more readable. It's more of the opposite... I've never seen someone use that, because an if statement is very straight forward.

Comment: This really feels like an XY problem. What advantage do you feel a ternary expression would have here, over an if statement?

Comment: Using `&&` operator may be better. (Using `if` is better) `ShowDebug && (DebugRender(), 0);`

Comment: Generally speaking, the conditional operator is intended to make an if statement with an assignment. `a = b ? c : d`. If you're using it for fancy inlining of `if-else`, it's counter-intuitive. Valid, but nevertheless counter-intuitive; and remember that you're writing code for your teammates to read.

Comment: The purpose of the conditional operator (or conditional expression) is to choose between two values. If you don't have two values to choose from, or aren't interested in a value, it's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Cleaner simpler code. That's it. Isn't that the sole purpose of a Ternary Operator?

Comment: Clean coding suggests brevity to ease cognitive strain whilst reading code, not to reduce on typing. This is not cleaner, and may even be worse.